# Compare and sort 2d array by its sub-value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have seen so many duplicate questions for these.Really sorry for duplicate question.But not found the correct solution or may be not get correct logic. I have already used usort() for these.
I have following array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 808
            [ScreenName] => Dispatch
            [OriginalName] => First Unit on Scene
            [OriginalPrintName] => First Unit on Scene
            [CurrentName] => Blank
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 809
            [ScreenName] => Dispatch
            [OriginalName] => EMS Agency
            [OriginalPrintName] => EMS Agency
            [CurrentName] => Blank
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 597
            [ScreenName] => Dispatch
            [OriginalName] => Date
            [OriginalPrintName] => Date
            [CurrentName] => Date 
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 509
            [ScreenName] => Dispatch
            [OriginalName] => Incident #
            [OriginalPrintName] => Incident #
            [CurrentName] => Incident #
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 758
            [ScreenName] => Dispatch
            [OriginalName] => Run# /Call #
            [OriginalPrintName] => Run#
            [CurrentName] => Run Call 
        )
)
```

By using following condition

```
if (($y2->CurrentName == "") || ($y2->CurrentName == "Blank")) {
    print  $y2->OriginalName ;
} else {
    print  $y2->CurrentName ;
}
```

In list, printing all CurrentName but
If currenName is blank then printing OriginalName
something like these.

```
Date
Incident #
Run Call
Type Of Service Req
Complaint Reported
Response Urgency
Location Type
Address Type
Address
Address Cont
```

I want to show these list albhabetically sorted.
My usort() function is

```
    usort($yvals, function ($elem1, $elem2) {
      if (($elem1->CurrentName == "" || $elem1->CurrentName == "Blank") && ($elem2->OriginalName == "" || $elem2->OriginalName == "Blank")) {
      return strcmp($elem1->OriginalName, $elem2->OriginalName);
  }else if(($elem1->CurrentName != "" || $elem1->CurrentName != "Blank") && ($elem2->CurrentName == "") || ($elem2->CurrentName == "Blank")){
       return strcmp($elem1->CurrentName, $elem2->OriginalName);
  }else{
     return strcmp($elem1->CurrentName, $elem2->CurrentName);
  }
});
```

Its working somewhere but not for all.

Comment: What is the current output and what is the expected output? Please add more details than just "not working" so that people can understand the issue you're having.

Comment: what are you trying to get?

Comment: show input and output please

Comment: I need final list to be alphabetically sorted.Please check edited list

Answer (score 0):

Try [strcasecmp](http://www.php.net/strcasecmp) in place of strcmp...

Answer (score 0):

This might be not optimal, but my experience with iterating over objects in php in some cases can produce counter-intuitive results, for the sake of simplicity I would separate sorting from filtering which you trying to achieve in one go.
Also parenting your objects to a working class and moving the name retrieval to a method would be good programming practice.

```
class SomeWorkingClass{
    public function getProperName(){
    // proper name retrieval functionality
  }
}

usort($yvals, function ($elem1, $elem2) {
     return strcmp($elem1->getProperName(), $elem2->getProperName());
}
```